# How do I know when to use {}

Tags: javascript, curly-brackets

I am new to learning JavaScript. I am starting to get the hang of it but I am reviewing lines of code that I got from a book I am learning from ("Head First") and I am having a bit of a hard time understanding when to use `{}`

Could you please help me understand?

```
function touchrock() {
    if (userName) {
        alert("I am glad that you have returned " + userName + "! Let's continue searching for your dream car");
    } else {
        userName = prompt("What is your name?");
        if (userName) {
            alert("It is good to meet you, " + userName + ".").onblur = setCookie;
            if (navigator.cookieEnabled);
            else alert("Sorry. Cookies aren't supported");
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("lambo").src = "lamboandgirl.jpg";
    document.getElementByID("lambo").onblur = setCookie;
}
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Statements

Comment: Put brackets everywhere unless there's only one statement and it can fit in a _single_ line.

Comment: Additionally, it defines `scope`.

Answer (score 2):

For a `function`, you always need to use it:

```
function () {
    // ...
}
```

For an `if` statement or an `else` statement it's optional, however if used without braces then it can only execute a single line

```
if (cond)
    // single line...
else
    // single line...

if (cond) {
    // multi ...
    // line ...
} else {
    // multi ...
    // line ...
}
```

You can even mix and match with `if`/`else`

```
if (cond)
{
    // multi ...
    // line ...
}
else
    // single line...
```

Also try to use the standard of opening braces `{` start at the end of the line and ending braces `}` at the start of the next line. This is the usual standard way of writing JavaScript.

```
function test(cond) {
    if (cond) {
        alert('hello world');
    } else {
        alert('awww');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort of optional... Without braces, only the first line will be inside the conditionals.

Comment: While curly-braces are optional for if/else statements, I find that it's smart to use them for a few reasons.  It makes your code more consistent, it's easier to read, and it avoids logic errors.

Comment: @SurrealDreams That's one of those holy wars of programming, to enforce curly brace blocks or not to.

Answer (score 2):

Using `if` statements like that is confusing and should be avoided. It also looks like there's a global variable floating around in there.

You can omit the brackets only for single-line blocks:

```
while (condition)
    console.log(2);

// Is the same as

while (condition) {
    console.log(2);
}
```

But *not* for multi-line blocks:

```
while (condition)
    console.log(2);
    console.log(3);

// Is the same as

while (condition) {
    console.log(2);
}

console.log(3);
```

Just stick to using brackets everywhere. I only omit them (sometimes) on `if` statements where the body is only one line long *and* there's no `else` block:

```
if (condition) break;

// Is the same as

if (condition) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of using {} is separate blocks of code.

```
function touchrock() { // Create a block of code
    if (userName) { // Create another one
        alert("I am glad that you have returned " + userName + "! Let's continue searching for your dream car");
    } else {
        userName = prompt("What is your name?");
        if (userName) {
            alert("It is good to meet you, " + userName + ".").onblur = setCookie;
            if (navigator.cookieEnabled);
            else alert("Sorry. Cookies aren't supported");
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("lambo").src = "lamboandgirl.jpg";
    document.getElementByID("lambo").onblur = setCookie;
} // End of the first block
```